USB device not detected upon quest when I usb passthrough using qemu
I run an Ubuntu Iso as:
#!/bin/bash

MEM_SIZE=4096

qemu-system-x86_64 \
-accel kvm \
-cpu host \
-m ${MEM_SIZE} \
-M q35 \
-bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd \
-device qemu-xhci \
-usb -device usb-host,vendorid=0x2357,productid=0x010c \
-cdrom /home/pcmagas/Λήψεις/Isos/Ubuntu/64/ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

And I try to usb-passthrough the device:
$ lsusb | grep "TP-Link"
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:010c TP-Link TL-WN722N v2/v3 [Realtek RTL8188EUS]

But upon my LiveCD I booted I do not see it (I have not setup the shared clipboard upon qemu yet):

But I did compare using Virtualbox and works like fine:


Edit 1
I did:
$ ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/004
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 3 Ιουν 23 21:42 /dev/bus/usb/001/004

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0732 Genesys Logic, Inc. All-in-One Cardreader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 4e53:5407  USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:010c TP-Link TL-WN722N v2/v3 [Realtek RTL8188EUS]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub



Why do you have -usb between the host controller and the passthrough'd device? Also, what's the permission of the device /dev/bus/usb/xxx/xxx (assuming you are not running qemu as root)?

@TomYan I am running as normal user.

Running as root did fix the issue. Is there a way to do it as a normal user???

Fix the permission of the device node of the respective USB device (with chmod for a volatile change; with udev rule for a persistent change).

But Virtualbox allow me to usb passthrough withoput sudo only qemu needs sudo. Maybe it is a group issue.

Not exactly. I mean, VirtualBox creates/uses its own sets of dev nodes under /dev/vboxusb/ to access the USB devices. Those dev nodes' owner group is vboxusers, which you can add your user to. However, qemu does not use those. As you can see, dev nodes under /dev/bus/usb/, which qemu uses, has the owner group of root. You will need to either set the permission for "others" to rw (it's just r now, as you can see), or add an ACL entry for it (like what uaccess in a udev rule would result in).

Run it using SUDO (or as a root user):
#!/bin/bash

MEM_SIZE=4096

sudo qemu-system-x86_64 \
-accel kvm \
-cpu host \
-m ${MEM_SIZE} \
-M q35 \
-bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd \
-device qemu-xhci \
-usb -device usb-host,vendorid=0x2357,productid=0x010c \
-cdrom /home/pcmagas/Λήψεις/Isos/Ubuntu/64/ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

USB device will be available upon vm.

ohh my god. Thanks for answer. 1h spending with this mess :)
